# Matplotlib ListedColormap transparent color

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, colormap

Is possible to use in own colormap transparent color?

This is how I am using custom colormap:

```
colors = ["#E04848", "#EE6C6C", "#F89090", "#FEB4B4", "#FFD8D8", "#FFFFFF", "#FFFFFF", "#D8D8FF", "#B4B4FF", "#9090FF", "#6C6CFF", "#4848FF"]

cmap= matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap(colors)

m = plt.contourf(xi, yi, zi, levels=boundaries, cmap = cmap, vmin=boundaries_list[0], vmax=boundaries_list[-1])

plt.colorbar(m, spacing="proportional")
```

Is possible to get "#FFFFFF" 100% transparent?

Comment: `"#FFFFFF"` is the RGB value of opaque white. You can instead create an RGBA value as `"#FFFFFF00"` with zero alpha.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I already tried.  ValueError: to_rgba: Invalid rgba arg "#FFFFFF00"
to_rgb: Invalid rgb arg "#FFFFFF00"
invalid hex color string "#ffffff00"

Comment: Which matplotlib version are you using?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest 1.4.2

Comment: Ok. That version is really old, and did not yet support rgba hex values.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Now I am using version 2.0 but transparent parts of colorer are still white... I can't se image through this white parts. img=mpimg.imread('image.png')
plt.imshow(img,aspect='auto',origin='lower',extent=[max(xi), min(xi), max(yi), min(yi)])

Answer (score 2):

ListedColormap accepts RGBA values as tuples. `(0,0,0,0)` will result in a transparent color.